# Chrome turns circles animation into squres

Tags: css, animation

When zooming-in and out, or moving between tabs, Chrome browsers ruins the animation of circle divs.

Check this animation for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ghuhfya5/4/

```
body {
    background-color: orange;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    animation: ripple 6s 0.5s ease-out infinite;
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

@keyframes ripple {
        0% {
          transform: scale(1);
          opacity: 0.9;
        }
        80%, 100% {
          transform: scale(500);
          opacity: 0;
        }
```

In chrome, zoom-in and zoom-out (Ctrl +/-), will change the circles into rectangles/squares.

In addition, try to refresh with F5, during the refresh move to another tab and wait for 2-3 seconds, then go back to the jsfiddle tab. It usually ruins the animation too (sometimes hard to reproduce).

There are more scenarios that cause the animation to be ruined.

In Firefox, everything works great. Try these scenarios in Firefox, and you'll see the animations works as expected.

Comment: I don't think you should worry about it =P when you zoom in/out a lot of weird stuff happens. it would be impractical to account for it all.

Comment: Yes... But it happens in other scenarios as well. When I do something in other tabs for a while, and then goes back to the tab with the animation, it also happens.

Comment: That's a pretty interesting bug, as far as I know.  Maybe you could [write a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list)?

Comment: Bug reported: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=536606

Answer (score 0):

Workaround was found:

The initial size of the div should be more than 2px and 1 px border radius.

It solves most of the problems, like zoom-in and zoom-out.

http://jsfiddle.net/ghuhfya5/17/

```
body {
    background-color: orange;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    animation: ripple 6s 0.5s ease-out infinite;
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

@keyframes ripple {
        0% {
          transform: scale(0.0025);
          opacity: 0.9;
        }
        80%, 100% {
          transform: scale(12.5);
          opacity: 0;
        }
```